# Hides Elements in Head

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I want to hide a couple of elements. I am able to do that but screen updates for a few milliseconds while hiding elements, so it's visible to users (not so smooth).

I am using the code below in `<head>`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
      $('.section').css('display', 'none');
      $('#tutorial-topic').css('display', 'none');

});
```

Later in `<body>` I am showing these hidden elements after the user is logged in.

```
// Show tutorial when user is logged in:
$(document).ready(function() {
  var CONTROL_INTERVAL4 = setInterval(function(){
  if($('#fireblaze-signin-ui').is(':hidden')){

      $('.section').css('display', '');
      $('#tutorial-topic').css('display', '');
      clearInterval(CONTROL_INTERVAL4);
    
} }, 200);
});
```

I tried this via CSS (instead of JS) in head-

```
.section {display : none}
#tutorial-topic {display : none}
```

Later when I run the code below to show elements, **it does not work** -

```
// Show tutorial when user is logged in:
$(document).ready(function() {
  var CONTROL_INTERVAL4 = setInterval(function(){
  if($('#fireblaze-signin-ui').is(':hidden')){

      $('.section').css('display', '');
      $('#tutorial-topic').css('display', '');
      clearInterval(CONTROL_INTERVAL4);
    
} }, 200);
});
```

I tried via `$('.section').show()`, it unhides elements, but it has conflict with other functionalities (some of them stopped working because of `.show()`. Any other solution?

Comment: why don't you try hiding it by default? like `<div style="display:none;"></div>` when the html is loaded and then if you went to show it you can do it with javascript.

there is no other option to hide the element smooth with javascript when the html is loaded until the javascript is loaded

Comment: Please click edit, then `[<>]` snippet editor and provide [mcve] - you can have more than one snippet to show different examples

Answer (score 0):

I will explain what is happening here.

When your html is rendered it the elements are by default is visible state.

```
<div class="section"> </div> 
<div id="tutorial-topic"> </div>
```

And when the script is rendered it hides the elements after they are loaded.

```
$('.section').css('display', 'none');
$('#tutorial-topic').css('display', 'none');
```

to avoid this and make it smooth you should have your elements hidden by default, that you can do either by adding inline style `display: none` or adding the same in the `CSS file`.

```
<div class="section" style="display:none;"> </div> 
<div id="tutorial-topic" style="display:none;"> </div>
```

OR

```
.section, #tutorial-topic{
  display: none;
}
```

And later when you want to show the elements whenever and wherever you want you just do.

```
$('.section, #tutorial-topic').show();
```